# SpringRest api auto add {? (curcly braces) after PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I create Spring RestFul API, I used swagger to test my APIs.

My case is described as below:

**URL 1 (not work)**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/api/my/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<MyDTO> getInfo(@PathVariable("id") Long courseId,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0", value = "pageNo") Integer pageNo,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "25", value = "pageSize") Integer pageSize,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "id", value = "sortBy") String sortBy) {
}
```

Swagger URL will generated as:

> http://localhost:8080/api/my/1{?pageNo%2CpageSize%2CsortBy%7D=&pageNo=0&pageSize=25&sortBy=id

Error:

```
"detail": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
```

Because: the value of id is **1{**

I want to build the URL as:

> http://localhost:8080/api/my/1?pageNo=0&pageSize=25&sortBy=id

**URL 2 (worked- it means other components are corrected)**

It worked if I change all request to PathVariable like

```
@GetMapping(value = "/api/my/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<MyDTO> getInfo(@PathVariable("id") Long courseId,
        @PathVariable("pageNo") int pageNo, @PathVariable("pageSize") int pageSize) {
}
```

Swagger URL will generated as:

> http://localhost:8080/api/my/1/0/1

Anyone what's wrong in this case with URL1 above ?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I can't reproduce; I'll also suggest that if possible you conform your parameter names to the Spring Data standards, and then you can simply use `Page` and `Sort` as controller parameters.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- yep, it's too strange so I dont know why. U mean I shoul du Pageable params instead of multi RequestParam right ?

Comment: Correct. Spring will handle all of the logic for you automatically.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- yep, I tried to change using Pageable, it's more many options for RequestParam but still error. So I revert to see the request simpler